# Delete in the permalink Wordpress taxonomy father

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, parent-child, permalinks

I put a personalized taxonomy with a plugin in the permalink of Wordpress. This taxonomy is hierarchical. The child has two levels above him. I just want to leave my son.
Example:
**Africa/Algeria/Algeri**
I just want:
**Algeri**

My current URL is as follows:
**www.example.com/guide/africa/algeria/algeri/nome/ID**

I want it to be like this:
**www.example.com/guide/algeri/nome/ID**
that is, you just leave your son

The URL (*www.example.com/guide/algeri/nome/ID*) is working but is not changed in the back office and Wordpress front office despite being "False" in the Rewrite of the Taxonomy (use CPT UI plugin). I always see the original URL.

In the Wordpress permalink I wrote:
guide/%taxonomy%/%postname%/%post_id%

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with permalinks strings. But WordPress filters can help you. There is a filter called "post_link" in WordPress.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_link

So, let's say that you write such filter:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'remove_specified_part_from_link', 10, 3 );
function remove_specified_part_from_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename )
{
$permalink_array=explode("/",$permalink);
unset($permalink_array[4]);
return implode("/",$permalink_array);
}
```

When explode $permalink by "/", it will return "http:","","www.example.com","guide","africa","algeria","nome","ID".
So we see that 5th element should be removed. That's why we unset $permalink_array[4] and return imploded array which would be equal to "http://www.example.com/guide/algeria/algeri/nome/ID"